# Getting schema from JSON column using schema_of_json function

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The documentation of [schema_of_json](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.schema_of_json.html) says:

```
Parameters: 
    json: Column or str
           a JSON string or a foldable string column containing a JSON string.
```

But executing the following code where I provide a column raises an error:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.shell import spark

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ["""{"foo":"hello","bar":"world"}"""],
    ["""{"foo":"hello","bar":"world"}"""],
    ["""{"foo":"hello","bar":"world"}"""]
], ['json_column'])

df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- json_column: string (nullable = true)

df_schema = df.select('json_column', f.schema_of_json(f.col('json_column')).alias('schema'))
df_schema.show(truncate=False)

# pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'schema_of_json(`json_column`)' due to data type mismatch: 
# The input json should be a foldable string expression and not null; however, got `json_column`.;
```

The only way that I know to use this function is hard-coding a JSON object, but in a production scenario is useless because I can't parse dynamically the content column.

```py
df_schema = df.select('json_column', f.schema_of_json('{"foo":"hello","bar":"world"}').alias('schema'))
df_schema.show(truncate=False)
# +-----------------------------+------------------------------------+
# |json_column                  |schema                              |
# +-----------------------------+------------------------------------+
# |{"foo":"hello","bar":"world"}|STRUCT<`bar`: STRING, `foo`: STRING>|
# |{"foo":"hello","bar":"world"}|STRUCT<`bar`: STRING, `foo`: STRING>|
# |{"foo":"hello","bar":"world"}|STRUCT<`bar`: STRING, `foo`: STRING>|
# +-----------------------------+------------------------------------+
```

Am I missing to do some step or the documentation isn't clear how this should be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try rdd the df, get schema and infer new schema in a read.json

```
s=df.select(col('json_column').alias('j')).rdd.map(lambda x: x.j)#convert json column into an rdd

s.collect()

['{"foo":"hello","bar":"world"}',
 '{"foo":"hello","bar":"world"}',
 '{"foo":"hello","bar":"world"}']

sc=spark.read.json(s).schema# read the rdd's schema





df1=df.select('*', from_json('json_column', schema=sc).alias('jsonread'))# change string to struct 

df1.printSchema()
```

Comment: That's an interesting solution. Do you have an idea in which scenario `schema_of_json` could be used or at least be useful?

Comment: No unless I research

Comment: It's not necessary, I wanted to know a production scenario where you faced a problem and solved it using `schema_of_json`, but if not, your solution is enough for me.